# use databind on children object

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm just starting to play with knockout.js and integrating it with a grid widget. I need to set a databind to a checkbox for each row but the checkboxes are created within the widget and I have no access to it. What I do have is access to the cell containing the checkbox.

I believe I could maybe use jquery to add the attributes dynamically to each checkbox and only  then call applybindings, but I'm wondering whether I can set data-bind on the cell and tell knockout to "assign" it to its children (in this case always only one checkbox)?

Comment: You can't tell knockout to bind to children that aren't created yet. Maybe the grid widget has an event when a row is created? Not sure why you need to bind to the checkbox, but maybe you can use jQuery to listen to the `click` of that checkbox: `$(document).on("click", "td.your_cell input[type=checkbox]", function() { });`

Comment: While the checkboxes are being created, I can add attributes to the checkbox's cell (its container.). Only when all are created am I applying bindings. The question is, can I add the data-bind to the cell and use some special knockout syntax to say that that binding is to be applied to the checkbox within it.

Answer (score 0):

Rivers, you wouldn't want Knockout (or probably any other code) interfering with anything managed by another widget.  Generally you'd want to look for an API on that jqGrid that allows you to manage the underlying data.  If that's not an option on jqGrid and it's something that you really need, then you should look for a different grid tool.  Maybe a knockout-specific grid tool would work better for you, like koGrid : https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/KoGrid